# Best Way to Store Device Configuration for iOS Application

Tags: ios

I am developing an iOS application that is more of a permanent install type application, and it will be different per client.  So, I'm looking for the best way to install some type of a configuration on the device that the app can detect and in essence 'lock' it into a specific setting for a client.  I want this to persist even if an application is deleted.

Something like a mobileconfig file would be neat, but I don't think those can contain undefined variables or be read by the applications.

I'm curious what the best and cleanest approach would be for this.

Comment: it almost sounds like the target device needs to be jail broken for this to happen. What kind of settings do you want to persist?

Comment: I'm basically just looking for a single identifier for a client - and no the devices won't be jailbroken.

Comment: I just thought that you need data to persist on the actual device, not somewhere in your database. It's much easier otherwise, just use UUID.

Comment: See my note below - the device identifier provided by UIDevice is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer and comments have said this cannot REALLY be done without the device being jail broken. However... There is a possible alternative.

You can use [OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID) or [SecureUDID](http://secureudid.org/) to create a unique identifier, then create the configuration in your server database. The application will connect to your server to obtain the global configuration should the configuration file not exist. This way, if the user uses your application, then deletes the application and then reinstalls it, you will still have their configuration which the application can redownload and store locally on the device.